# ColdFusion URL Rewriting Missing

Tags: iis, coldfusion, url-rewriting

I am making a development copy of a ColdFusion website that I didn't make. Pages other than the homepage give a 404 Not Found error and I think it is because I am missing the URL rewriting. What did I miss when copying the website?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the application? Is it using a community supported framework? What should the URls look like, maybe someone can help write a rewrite rule for you.

Comment: There is no community supported framework being used and the URLs are formatted like this: /en/Contact-Us, where en is the short language code. Writing my own rewrite rule would not be difficult. However I need the development site to work the same as the live site and I am not sure what the 'ugly' URL would be.

Comment: The server is using IIS 8.0

Comment: Pretty sure that if rewrite rules are being used in IIS that a file named `web.config` would be created in the web root. Are you certain one is not there? Have you looked at the IIS config for the site on the server to see if any rewrite rules are set up? Also, try dumping out the CGI scope on one of the pages you think is rewritten, you should be able to see the URL that gets passed to CF.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good chance your URL rewriting is handled by an `.htaccess` or `web.config` file, which would require the correct OS and/or htaccess parser to be installed. For example the original site might be using ISAPI rewrite or Helicon APE, to parse an `.htaccess` file. You may have copied all the files to your new environment but without the parsing, you would not have the URL rewriting. The previous host may be able to help shed some light.

Comment: There is no .htaccess or web.config file. Any other ideas?

Comment: Without more details, there's no way to know what you're dealing with. It is possible the rewrites were set up somewhere else on the server. You'll likely have to check with the previous developer and/or host, or hire somebody to dig through the code and help sort it out for you.